# vba loop texttocolumns in all worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, loops

So, in a workbook I have a lot of sheets from which I want to use texttocolumns for a Date, the date is usually something like "11/22/2018 10:59:59 AM" and I only want it to do a MDY  with a delimited text to columns. The delimiter must be false.

```
Sub LoopCertain() 'Excel VBA to exclude sheets
'SP Edit, error handler
   On Error Goto errHandler
   If False Then
errHandler:
      MsgBox Err.Description
'This will cause the routine to carry on where it left off
      Resume Next
   End If
'SP End of Edit
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim objRange1 As Range
Dim objRange2 As Range

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
Select Case ws.Name
Case Is = "General", "Verification", "OEM Plant Summary"
'No Code here if excluded
Case Else

    'Set up the ranges
    Set objRange1 = Range("C:C")
    Set objRange2 = Range("I:I")
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

       'Do the first parse
    objRange1.TextToColumns _
      Destination:=Range("C1"), _
      DataType:=xlDelimited, _
      Tab:=False, _
      Semicolon:=False, _
      Comma:=False, _
      Space:=False, _
      Other:=False, _
      OtherChar:="-"

    'Do the second parse
    objRange2.TextToColumns _
      Destination:=Range("I1"), _
      DataType:=xlDelimited, _
      Tab:=False, _
      Semicolon:=False, _
      Comma:=False, _
      Space:=False, _
      Other:=False, _
      OtherChar:="-"
End Select
Next ws
End Sub
```

I get errors when trying to run this. I need to change Columns "I" and "C" and results must be in the same column. Appreaciate if you can help since I have been like the whole week trying different types of loops and nothing works. This one work if I remove the Loop though...

Here is the sample data:
[image: Sample Data]

Comment: Let's see some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: added the sample data to the post. Thank you

Comment: There is a distinct lack of any error checking and handling in your code, you assume that everything is as you have supplied in the sheet with no checking for invalid ranges or data.  For starters add an error handler to the subroutine.

Answer (score 0):

A fixed width would probably be more appropriate. Your sample data leaves some unanswered questions but I'll assume a mmddyyyy (not mdyyyy) date format and data that either starts in row 1 or has a header label in row 1 with 10 or less characters.

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Select Case ws.Name
        Case "General", "Verification", "OEM Plant Summary"
            'No Code here if excluded
        Case Else

            With ws.Range("C:C")
                .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
                               FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, xlMDYFormat), Array(10, xlSkipColumn))

            End With

            With ws.Range("I:I")
                .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
                               FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, xlMDYFormat), Array(10, xlSkipColumn))

            End With

    End Select
Next ws
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use TextToColumns? I would be tempted to convert the text to a proper date (meaning a date serial number) and then format the column in whichever way you want to display the date. The advantage of this method would be that you can actually retain the time value contained in the date if case you want to know it later but without displaying it.

However, since you are intending to manipulate the text I think the code below is more efficient. Please try it.

```
Sub ReformatDate()

    Const FirstDataRow As Long = 1          ' change as appropriate

    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Arr As Variant
    Dim C As Long
    Dim i As Long

    For Each Ws In Worksheets
        If InStr(1, ",General,Verification,OEM Plant Summary", "," & Ws.Name, _
                 vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        With Ws
            For C = 3 To 9 Step (9 - 3)         ' columns C & I
                Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(FirstDataRow, C), _
                                 .Cells(.Rows.Count, C).End(xlUp))
                Arr = Rng.Value
                For i = 1 To UBound(Arr)
                    If Len(Arr(i, 1)) Then Arr(i, 1) = Split(Arr(i, 1))(0)
                Next i
                Rng.Value = Arr
                .Columns(C).AutoFit
            Next C
        End With
    Next Ws
End Sub
```

Comment: That error indicates a typo. In the error notification, press the `Debug` button. Then look at the line of code which is highlighted. If you can't spot the fault tell me which line it is.